# Count distinct values per distinct id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

Version: mySQLi PHP 5.4.45

I'm trying to count the number of panels per unique ID. Instead, I'm getting the total number of tests per ID.

Before Query: (example)

```
eReq | panel_name | test
------------------------
 500 | tox        | Butabital
 500 | tox        | Amphetamine
 500 | tox        | MethAmp
 500 | chem       | CBC
 600 | tox        | Morphine
 600 | chem       | CBC
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT panel_name, count(*)
FROM `ordered_codes` 
JOIN samples ON ordered_codes.tox_id = samples.tox_id
JOIN orders_codes ON ordered_codes.code_id = orders_codes.id
GROUP BY panel_name
```

**Current Results:**

```
   panel_name | Count(*)
   ---------------------
   tox        | 4
   chem       | 2
```

**Needed Results:** (Numbers should be lower - counting panel_name by eReq)

```
panel_name | Count(*)
---------------------
tox        | 2
chem       | 2
```

I feel like this is very simple, I'm just overthinking at this point.

Comment: I don't understand why there are two joins to `ordered_codes`.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `count(distinct)`?

```
SELECT panel_name, count(distinct ereq)
FROM ordered_codes oc JOIN
     samples s 
     ON oc.tox_id = s.tox_id 
GROUP BY panel_name
```

I don't understand why there are two joins to `ordered_codes`, so I removed the second, assuming it is a typo.  Your query will generate a syntax error.